# MS Access Form single entry text box for barcode for multiple columns

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2016

What I need is a single text box where I can scan a barcode. Every scan gets saved to a column in the table.

Table

```
1-----2----3----4----x1----x2----x3----x4
123--123--123--123---23----23----23----23
```

where 123 is the barcode entered in the form, and the "x1x2x3" are extracted from the barcode entered in the "123" by calculated field.

I have the rest figured out somewhat but I can't seem to find a way to have a single text box to enter number to different columns.

To clarify I want help in the form section,  I need help on where I can scan the upc code in one box and have data captured from that upc saved in a 1 column in the table and the next upc scanned will be saved in another column.  How can I accomplish this thru vba or any other method.  In the form I'll have a date and around 56 boxes where the scanned barcode will be saved for each boxes.

Comment: You want to split up barcode into several fields? That would require code (VBA or macro) to save each piece to fields/textboxes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That looks like your data isn't normalised. You should probably simply store the barcode as a single field, maybe with a "datescanned" field. 
Then you can extract the calculated part in a query whenever you need it, no need to store it separately?